# nested select database sql query

Tags: php, sql

how to order a values fetched from database??

```
SELECT * FROM comment;
------------------------------------
| commentid | content | read_unread|
------------------------------------
1              hello      Unread
2              hi         read    


Select * From replies;
//commentid Fk from table "  comment  " so it means row 1 from table comments has 2 replies
------------------------------------
| repnum | rep_content | commentid |
------------------------------------
1              see ya        1
2              ok            1
```

i want to show this in a table html/php like this

---

```
comment num |  Content | replies count
--------------------------------------------------   
 1              hello    2
 2              hi       0
```

//the "replies count 2" came from the table replies replied to commentid 1 from table comment

how can i show this in a single query sql order by the count of the replies count???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT a.commentid, a.content, count(b.repnum) as replies_count 
FROM comment a left join replies b on a.commentid = b.commentid 
GROUP by a.commentid
```

Comment: i have a table column in replies named Rep_or_Not, i make a condition count(*) as replies_count" = the count where Rep_or_not !='Replied'

Comment: i have a table column in replies named Rep_or_Not, i make a condition count(*) as replies_count" = the count where Rep_or_not !='Replied', displays all values including that has no replies

Comment: i made a change to my syntax and i get it thanks again fo the replies =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` on SQL query :

```
SELECT c.commentid, c.content, COUNT(r.replies) FROM comment c JOIN replies r ON r.commentid = c.commentID GROUP BY c.commentid, c.content;
```

More infos here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
SELECT a.commentid, a.content, count(*) as replies_count
FROM comment a
LEFT JOIN replies b on a.commentid=b.commentid
GROUP BY a.commentid, a.content
```

Comment: i hava a table column named Rep_or_not in TABLE replies  i want to display all row values but, display  WHERE COUNT of Rep_or_not !='Replied' ...thanks

Comment: your above query displays all row with their replies count,but theres a condition if Rep_or_not !='Replied' then display ALL but with the count of Rep_or_not !='Replied'.... i mean " count(*) as replies_count" = the count where Rep_or_not !='Replied' hehe..

Answer (score 0):

Left join and count from replies table is your buddies. Inner join will remove `comments` those don't yet get any `replies` so here left join will be required. And count from `replies` is your requirement so count(*) will not work.

```
SELECT A.commentid AS comment_num, A.content AS Content, count(B.commentid) as replies_count
FROM comment A
LEFT JOIN replies B on A.commentid=B.commentid
GROUP BY A.commentid, A.content
```